# Should I use quotes to echo multiple words in bash?

Tags: bash

In shell scripts I usually use `echo` to print a message. When the message contains multiple words I have to options of how to do that:

```
# No quotes
echo Hello SO
```

or

```
# Quotes
echo 'Hello SO'
```

Is one way better than the other?

I know that quotes are very important when there are variables, special character, etc. So, this is another question.

Comment: `Is one way better than the other?` For me it's better, because words in quotes are displayed in different color in my editor. So I immediately "see" by color, if argument is a string or it's some kind of option.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, neither is the best, other one is just better suited for that job.  I guess it would boil down to `echo`ing a var: With `echo "$var"`you are better prepared for the worst and you have the possibility to clean up the var before `ècho`ing. Also `echo "a` [ctrl]+[q] [ctrl]+[j] `b"` won't work without quotes (shell).

Comment: Thanks @Quasímodo, but I think that the phrasing is okay. I understand, that some arguments for either of ways can be opinionated, but I hope to also get an answer based on facts (if there is such answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Echo varies a lot accross implementations, but [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) does mandate this:

> **STDOUT**
> The echo utility arguments shall be separated by single <space> characters and a <newline> character shall follow the last argument.

So if you don't quote, the shell will do its job and split the arguments on the whitespaces and then Echo will output each argument separated from the other by a single space:

```
$ echo Y X Z
Y X Z
$ echo Y   X   Z
Y X Z
$ echo 'Y   X   Z'
Y   X   Z
```

And of course, the whole line can still contain special tokens and fail altogether:

```
# Variable expansion
$ echo I have $2
I have
```

```
# Filename expansion
$ echo hi * there
hi Documents Downloads Music Pictures Videos there
```

```
# And other special tokens
$ echo hello (I am I)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

When in doubt, quote it. For your particular example, no, it makes no difference.